# What value can I set MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT to in order to reset it to the next available value

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table with indexed IDs like:

```
ID Name
1  abc
2  def
4  ghi
9  jkl
10 mno
11 xyz
```

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is siting at **12** in this example.

If I delete the 2 rows with IDs 10 and 11, would `ALTER TABLE`table_name`AUTO_INCREMENT=1` reset the AI value to **10** or would it try to set it to **3** and thus break my table?

I am trying to set a standard AI reset that sets the value to the next available sequence in all cases.

Thanks for confirming the right way to set the query statement.

Comment: You should not use auto_increment for that. Use a rank column.

Comment: ? never heard of or used that @juergend -- I need to look into that. Thanks

Comment: Not sure that rank column relates to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1` did what I was hoping it would do.

Answer (score 0):

Using [ALTER TABLE](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/reseting-mysql-autoincrement-column/), of course:

ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

But you can't reset it to less than the maximum value used, for that you'll need to remove the column using [ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) and re-add it with ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN [col] AUTO INCREMENT. However (there's always a caveat with MySQL), this will not work if your table is using the NDB engine.

Comment: well, I was hesitant to test it on my database but I did test ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1 with the AI value equal to **1** and it worked. Do you think that is dangerous to do?